# Explicitly import only some objects from a module

Tags: python

I would like to use the `radians` and `degrees` functions from the `numpy` module. However, `numpy` is friggin' huge, and I don't want to import the whole thing, i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
```

I can do this the usual way:

```
from numpy import radians, degrees
```

However, I prefer the syntax `np.degrees` because of its explicitness.

Here is how I have been doing this; basically I import the objects/functions I want from the module, then I create a "dummy" `np` object in which to store the imported objects/functions:

```
from numpy import radians, degrees
np = type('', (object,), dict(radians = radians, degrees = degrees))
del degrees
del radians
```

It seems as if there has to be a better, more straightforward way of doing this. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import numpy as np` is no slower than `from numpy import radians, degrees`. Both evaluate the entire module first; the only difference is what is added to the global namespace of the importing module afterwards. (If anything, the *second* is slower, because it adds two items to the namespace instead of just one.)

So, just use `import numpy as np`, and don't worry about the things you aren't using.

Comment: After a bit of testing it is clear you're absolutely right.